# Pattern to prevent continually checking error?

Tags: c, error-handling, embedded

In C, is there a pattern that removes the need to continually check for errors in functions that call other functions?

e.g. If function foo() calls a(), b() and c() one after the other the return value from each has to be checked before continuing. if a(), b(), or c() also call other functions, which possibly also call other functions, this leaves a long sequence of error checking of possibly the same error...

```
int16_t a(x_t x) {return DO_SOME_WORK(x);}

int16_t b(y_t y) {return DO_OTHER_WORK(y);}

int16_t c(z_t z) {return DO_MORE_WORk(z);}

foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) {
    int16_t err = 0;
    // I can handle errors returned by either:
    err = a(x));
    if (err) return err;
    err = b(y);
    if (err) return err;
    err = c(z); 
    return err;

    // Or
    err = a(x);
    if (!err) err = b(y);
    if (!err) err = c(z);
    return err;
}
```

I prefer the second method as there is a clear single exit point, but the other localises the handling and either method introduces a lot of ifs, and with a large program, that's lots of extra code, especially in functions that do nothing but call other functions and pass along the output between them, for example.
Thanks

Comment: I think the only other real way would be to "simulate exceptions" via `setjmp` and `longjmp`, but then your program flow becomes a lot less easier to follow. Also, a common compiler optimization is to coalesce all of those `return err` statements into one, and insert conditional branches to that statement.

Comment: Are the `err` values 0 and 1 or are there many different `err` values?  Depending on the answer, there are different idioms to use.

Comment: @chux there are many different err values, in the upper level functions that they are ultimately returned to they are pushed to an error queue for reporting to a parent system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you could exploit short-circuit evaluation of `&&`, where when the left hand operand is `false`, the right-hand operand is not evaluated.

If you might want to perform other processing between calls to `a()`, `b()` or `c()`, the following allows that:

```
bool foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    bool err = a( x );
    err = err && b( y ) ;
    err = err && c( z ) ; 

    return err;
}
```

whereas if the function is composed solely of calls `a()`, `b()` or `c()`, then you can use the even more terse:

```
bool foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    return a( x ) && 
           b( y ) && 
           c( z ) ; 
}
```

---

### [added in response to comment]

Solving @kkrambo's point about any numeric value of the function return not being propagated to the caller can be solved but is increasingly less attractive as a solution:

```
int16_t foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    int16_t ret ;

    bool err = (ret = a( x ));
    err = err && (ret = b( y )) ;
    err = err && (ret = c( z )) ; 

    return ret ;
}
```

or

```
int16_t foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    uint16_t ret ;

    (ret = a( x )) && 
    (ret = b( y )) && 
    (ret = c( z )) ;

    return ret ; 
}
```

---

Increasing in horribleness you could even do:

```
int16_t foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    int16_t err ;

    if( (err = a(x)) ) {}
    else if( (err = b(y)) ) {} 
    else if( (err = c(z)) ) {}

    return err ; 
}
```

Simplifies to the following where `err` is boolean:

```
bool foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) 
{
    bool err = true ;

    if( a(x) ) {}
    else if( b(y) ) {} 
    else if( c(z) ) {}
    else { err = false }

    return err ; 
}
```

Comment: Technically you _could_ do this, but the next person to maintain your code will hate you.  :)

Comment: In the original question the functions return 0 on success or a non-zero value that could identify a variety of error conditions.  But for your suggestion the functions would have to return true on success or false for all possible errors.  Any descriptive error code would be lost.

Comment: @AndrewCottrell : The advisability of the code is a different question.  I think from that point of view the first pattern is preferable to the second, but repeatedly evaluates `err`. Succinct and "clever" are not always better.

Comment: @kkrambo : That is true, but in the example the return is used only as a boolean within `foo()`, although any the numeric value of `err` is propagated and returned to the caller of `foo()`, so this code is not perhaps equivalent and may not meet all requirements.

Answer (score 3):

If each function call of a function needs error checking then every time you call that function you should check for errors. The reason is even though it is the same function the inputs are different and the global (and static local) variable are different changing the results. What this means is that if you want to check for errors you are not actually wasting the computational work.

Edit: I don't know if this is wise but you can use Macros to clean up the syntax of

```
err = a(x);
if(err) return err;
```

It would look something like

```
#define error_check(f, e) \
e = f; \
if(e) return e;
```

So in your code you can just write

```
error_check(a(x),err)
```

I am not expeirenced with macros but this should work.

Comment: Very nice this thought: "for every function call, parameters or global variables can have different values; so, if you want to check for errors, you are not wasting work". Really, very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Since the goal it to return an error code and not simple a boolean, OP supplied 2 approaches are at least reasonable, if not preferable.  Short circuit code like `if (a(x) || b(x)) return true` fails to maintain the `err` value derived from `a()` and `b()`.

It comes down to style.

If code simple consisted of a few lines, any approach would suffice.  But given there may  exist significant code interwoven between `a(x)`, `b(x)` and `c(x)`, recommend against style 2 as it separates flow over many lines of code.  I like style 3 over 1 as it is a bit more terse, but the differences between 1 & 3 is small.

To cope with style #2 ability to collect error return in one spot, consider a higher level function wrapper that unequivocally insures all prologue and epilogue activity occurs.

Best choice: go with group's style guidelines, else what work best for you to *maintain*, not write.

```
int16_t foo (x_t x, y_t y, z_t z) {  // added matching return type
    int16_t err = 0;

    // OP style 1
    err = a(x));
    if (err) return err;
    err = b(y);
    if (err) return err;
    err = c(z); 
    return err;

    // OP style 2
    err = a(x);
    if (!err) err = b(y);
    if (!err) err = c(z);
    return err;

    // style 3
    // via enum or define, create an OK symbol
    if ((err = a(x)) != OK) return err;
    if ((err = b(x)) != OK) return err;
    if ((err = c(x)) != OK) return err;
    // 
}
```