# How can I encapsulate a function like this in C?

Tags: c, function

I want write a struct to encapsulate some function like this:

```
typedef struct _Operate {
    void *              op_fun;
    size_t         result_type;
    unsigned int     arg_count;
    size_t          arg_type[];
} * Operate;
```

Here `op_fun` is the function pointer this operation does. `result_type` is the type that function returns. `arg_count` is count of arguments, and `arg_type` keep the type of arguments. In other words, the `op_fun` is like this:

```
result_type ( * op_fun)(type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2, ... , type_N arg_N);
```

The `N`, at first may be not known until `arg_cuont` has been given. `type_1` is `arg_type[1]`, and `type_2` is `arg_type[2]` and so on.

And my question is: **How to rebuild the function pointer?** Because when the function pointer became to `op_fun`, it became a `void *`. The information of its arguments and return type has been lost. I have to rebuild it by only given `result_type`, `arg_count` and `arg_type`.

At this condition it saves my lot time to develop, like this:

```
void traverseTree(TreeNode tree_root, Operate operate)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < tree_root->n_children; i++) {
        traverseTree(tree_root->children[i], operate);
    } 
    doOperate(operate, tree_root); 
}
```

So that I don't have to write these code every times when traverse the tree( it acturally saved my time).

But I want it is not a compile-time behavior, that is just a
syntactic sugar. I wnat know if there is a methord to realize it.

Comment: You can't dynamically construct a function call like that.  Why do you want to do this?  What problem do you think having this functionality would solve?

Comment: "_Because when the function pointer became to `op_fun`, it became a `void *`_" - And how did you do that? Afaik, you can't cast a function pointer to `void*`. _If_ you could, you should be able to cast it back I suppose...

Comment: The only way to do this portably is to have a great big `switch` (or equivalent) that encompasses all possibilities and casts `op_fun` appropriately in each case.  The compiler has to be able to see the type of the function to be called, at compile time, in order to emit the correct code for the call.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Not in ISO C, but this is a commonly available extension (e.g. POSIX guarantees it).

Comment: @NateEldredge Aha, ok, thanks - and then I suppose the cast back should also work?

Comment: how is it possible to store `type` into `size_t`?

Comment: @Loikeid But *why*?  How will having this make things easier for you?  This smells strongly of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: At this condition its save my lot time to develop:

```
void traverseTree(TreeNode tree_root, Operate operate) {
    for(int i = 0; i < tree_root->n_children; i++){
        traverseTree(tree_root->children[i], operate);
    }
    doOperate(operate, tree_root);
}
```

So that I don't have to write these code every times when traverse the tree.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo:  If I turned it to `void *`, I can turned it back when coding. But I want it works at running.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's unacceptable(XD)

Comment: @Loikeid If you want to support every possible signature for `op_fun` I don't think C is the correct language for this task. You are basically writing an interpreter for a new language. If you are willing to do parts of it in assembler, you could perhaps write the bulk of the code in C... Perhaps ...

Comment: If you seek a mechanism to turn static type-checking off, usually warning compiler flags are simpler.

Comment: Just handle single data and if user wants more data, just require the user to pass a pointer to a structure with the user data. `arg_type keep the type of arguments.` You can't keep type of arguments in `size_t`. `when the function pointer became to op_fun, it became a void *` How do you intent to call the function pointer after it becaome `void*`? C is a _statically_ typed programming language. Either you have to type it all out statically, or you are basically writing a new scripting language (in C).

Comment: `doOperate(operate, tree_root);` just `operate(tree_root)` and let it be `void (*op_fun)(TreeNode);`

Comment: You cannot use `void*` as a generic pointer for _function_ pointers, since it is only well-defined to use as a generic _object_ pointer. So you have incompatible pointer conversions, strict aliasing violations and all manner of undefined behavior.

Comment: Never hide pointers behind `typedef`. It only serves to make the code very confusing to read for everyone including yourself.

Comment: As for the question... don't. Just use a function pointer. This is a perfect example of "here is a solution with no problem that it solves. There are however lots problems I ran into when I implemented this solution..." Instead focus on an actual problem and then look at the best way to solve it. This is almost certainly not it.

Comment: Possibly-relevant information at [C late binding with unknown arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885868) and [How to push n arguments to stack without assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68184297).

Comment: @KamilCuk It acturally is by now, but I want it can be more generatic.

Comment: `it can be more generatic` `op_fun` has to know that it is going to work on `TreeNode`, or doesn't it? There is no point in creating abstract generalization if you do not need them. In other words, more generic _over what set_ of specializations? If `op_fun` is going to work on `TreeNode`, then it needs to work on `TreeNode`, not on something else. Either way, you have to write the specialization, and operating on `TreeNode` needs that specific specialization. And, well, statically typed programming languages help you by checking those types.

Comment: Ok so after posting all them grumpy comments I went ahead and coded together two ways of doing this the right way instead. I hope that answers how to solve the original problem. Answer found below.

Comment: `that I don't have to write these code every times when traverse the tree.` Do you have multiple trees specializations with different traversing functions? Could you share the code that you write "every time when traversing the tree"? C programming language has no templates - if you want "type template tree", then it's going to be [hard](https://github.com/tylov/STC/blob/master/include/stc/clist.h#L131) or you have to switch to language with templates.

Comment: @SteveSummit That may be a methord.

Comment: @KamilCuk : I have not many examples. But I believe it will be frequently used, Because there does exist a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Function calls cannot be dynamically created in this way.  If you want a way to generically call functions, you need to give them a common interface.

If you look at how the `pthread_create` function is defined:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

It takes a function pointer for the thread start function which takes a single `void *` argument and returns a `void *`, along with a `void *` representing the arguments.  Your `traverseTree` code should do the same:

```
void traverseTree(TreeNode tree_root, void *(*func)(TreeNode, void *), void *args)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < tree_root->n_children; i++) {
      traverseTree(tree_root->children[i], func, args); 
    }
    func(tree_root, args);
}
```

For a given function's arguments, you can create a struct containing those arguments and pass a pointer to it.  Then in the function, you would cast the `void *` argument to a pointer to the proper struct type.

Comment: It is. Now I acturally use `Operate` like this. 

```
void doOperate(Operate op, voidPtr op_obj) {
    op->result = ((voidPtr (*)(voidPtr))(op->op_fun))(op_obj);
}
```

Here `voidPtr` acturally is just `void *`. And `op->result` is where result to store.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to recast member `op_fun` to the desired function type.  So for example, if you have type defined:

```
result_type (op_fun_2_t)(type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2);
```

and object defined:

```
Operate my_obj = malloc ...;
```

and function defined:

```
result_type my_func(type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2);
```

and member `op_fun` set:

```
my_obj->op_fun = (void *)my_func;
```

Then you should be able to call my_func using an explicit cast:

```
((op_fun_2_t)(my_obj->op_fun))(type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2);
```

You will need to define a type associated with each possible combination of argument types and counts and make sure that you cast the function to the type assigned to `op_fun` in each case.  If it is cast to the wrong type, you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right. I difined `Operate` almost like this. But soon I recognized that the `result_type (op_fun_2_t)(type_1 arg_1, type_2 arg_2);` must be staticly given, and I need a dynamic methord.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know a priori the possible number of arguments and the type of each one.

If the return type differs, you define a union-object to make a common object of all the types.  So, instead of defining `result type` of type `size_t` you will define it as `union OBJECT` and make a dispatcher for each possible case.

If the arguments types can vary, this is more complicated and there are lots of ways to implement generic functions.  For example, use a trie which dispaches on ith level depending on the ith type.

Anyway, what you try to do is to implement generic functions and you can find literature on that to see how the systems do it.

Comment: You know my thought. 

I only have to know how a function is compiled，called and works, then I can make it. （´ཀ`）

Comment: @Loikeid you cannot know how a function is compiled.  For you, a C function is a pointer somewhere and this is all you know.  Even the calling discipline is not imposed by the ISO9899 and you cannot suppose much.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a so-called "XY problem" where you need to solve X and think Y is the right solution, so you ask about your problems implementing Y...

Ok so after some clarification, the actual problem you seem to want a solution to is how to do generic programming with a "traverse" function applied to some container. This is not something you need to re-invent the wheel for, there's well-known design patterns for this in C that have been used since the dawn of time.

For reference I'll give two different solutions, the "old school" solution and the modern C solution.

---

**"Old school" generic programming**

The old school version would involve using `void*` which is the generic *object* pointer (but cannot be used with function pointers). You'd design a callback function of a specified format taking void* as parameters. If you look at well-known libraries, `bsearch`, pthreads among others are using this method. Something along the lines of:

```
typedef void callback_t (void*);
```

Then we pass this to a generic "traverse" function, like this:

```
void traverse (void*       array, 
               size_t      item_size, 
               size_t      items, 
               callback_t* callback)
```

Depending on which callback and items we pass along, the algorithm is executed for that specific type. Full example:

```
typedef void callback_t (void*);

void traverse (void*       array, 
               size_t      item_size, 
               size_t      items, 
               callback_t* callback)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<items; i++)
  {
    unsigned char* cptr = array;
    callback( &cptr[i*item_size] );
  }
}

void print_int (void* arg)
{
  int* iptr = arg;
  printf("%d ", *iptr);
}

void print_string (void* arg)
{
  char* str = *(char**)arg;
  printf("%s ", str);
}


int main (void)
{
  int iarray[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
  traverse(iarray, sizeof(int), 10, print_int);
  puts("");
  
  char* strarray[2] = {"hello", "world"};
  traverse(strarray, sizeof(char*), 2, print_string);
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
hello world
```

---

**Modern C generic programming**

Less kind and grumpy people like me might call the previous version "old fart" generic programming. There's lots of obvious problems with it: we have to pass lots of arguments, it's not type safe at all, the API is cumbersome. Slip a key when implementing it and it crashes ungracefully somewhere unexpected - so it is hard to debug too.

Modern C features type-generic programming, which can detect types at compile time. We'd cook up an admittedly cryptic-looking macro like this:

```
#define print(array, arg)             \
  _Generic( (&array),                 \
            int(*)[]: print_int,      \
            char*(*)[]: print_string ) (arg)
```

This one takes an array as parameter, then checks if we can form *a pointer to that array* matching any of the supported forms. If not, compiler error. Type safe.

It then calls the appropriate callback function, which too as it turns out can be declared with the correct parameter type and not `void*`, so those turn type safe too. They'll look simple, like this:

```
void print_int (int* iptr)
{
  printf("%d ", *iptr);
}
```

Below follows an example with two different forms of generic tasks, a print task and a "increase array item by 1 task". This is 100% standard C as well:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int (int* iptr)
{
  printf("%d ", *iptr);
}

void print_string (char** str)
{
  printf("%s ", *str);
}

#define print(array, arg)             \
  _Generic( (&array),                 \
            int(*)[]: print_int,      \
            char*(*)[]: print_string ) (arg)

void inc_int (int* iptr)
{
  (*iptr)++;
}

void inc_string (char** str)
{
  // some nonsense increasing each character value
  for(char* s=*str; *s!='\0'; s++)
  {
    (*s)++;
  }
}

#define inc(array, arg)               \
  _Generic( (&array),                 \
            int(*)[]: inc_int,        \
            char*(*)[]: inc_string ) (arg)

#define traverse(array, action)       \
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array); i++) { action(array, &array[i]); }

int main (void)
{
  int iarray[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  // making this point to read/write compound literals instead of read-only string literals:
  char* strarray[2] = { (char[]){"hello"}, (char[]){"world"} };
  
  traverse(iarray, print); puts("");
  traverse(strarray, print); puts("");
  
  traverse(iarray, inc);
  traverse(iarray, print); puts("");
  
  traverse(strarray, inc);
  traverse(strarray, print); puts("");
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
hello world
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
ifmmp xpsme
```

To avoid code repetition, one can also really get crazy and define [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) which also creates the actual functions. Generally not a good idea because the code turns hard to read, if easy to maintain.

Comment: Thank you. But I know my question is just it. It should not be a compile-time behavior.