# Best practices for non-local exit with cleanup in C?

Tags: c, resource-management

What is considered best practice for aborting on errors in C?

In our code base we currently have a pattern using

```
#define CHECKERROR(code) if(code) { return code; }
```

but this leads to resources not being closed in code of the form

```
/* not actual code due to non-disclosure restrictions */
int somefunction() {
    handle_t res1, res2;
    int errorcode;

    res1 = getResource();
    res2 = getResource();

    errorcode = action1(res1, res2);
    CHECK(errorcode);
    errorcode = action2(res1, res2);
    CHECK(errorcode);

    freeResource(res1);
    freeResource(res2);
    return errorcode;
}
```

I came across the pattern

```
/* initialize resources */
do {
    /* ... */
    errorcode = action();
    if(errorcode) break;
    /* ... */
} while(0);
/* cleanup resources */
return errorcode;
```

before in articles, but couldn't find any source discussing it now.

What is a good practice, that would be considered idiomatic to C? Does the `do { } while(0);` pattern qualify? Is there an idiomatic way to make it more clear, that it is *not* intended to be a loop, but a block with non-local exit?

Comment: I like the question but as currently asked it asks for opinions and in its current form it will not stay open for long here on SO. The migration to SO requires that you update the question.

Comment: I am not sure if it is idiomatic, but I don't know a better solution than a `do { ... } while (0)` contruct, which really allows you to jump (read *break* as *go to*) error handling code.

Comment: there is no best practice. You may try "__cleanup__" attribute

Comment: there is a proposal to add "defer"mechanism to C23 to somehow standardize the error handling. Take a look on https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2020/12/14/a-defer-mechanism-for-c/

Comment: Did you consider to use `atexit()`?

Comment: @thebusybee `atexit()` would not be suitable in this case, because it will run only on program exit, not scope/function exit.

Comment: @nhatnq As I understand, the cleanup attribute only exists in GCC, which is a non-starter here.

Comment: Well, then as always: Write clean code. Express what you mean by common control structures, don't use "_fancy_" constructs or macros. The source you write is mainly read by humans, many times and long after being written, and should be easily understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is considered best practice for aborting on errors in C?
>
> What is a good practice, that would be considered idiomatic to C?

Really, nothing. There is no best-practice. Best is to tailor a specific solution to the specific case you are handling. For sure - concentrate on writing readable code.

Let's mention some documents. [MISRA](https://www.misra.org.uk/) 2008 has the following. The rule is strict - *single* exit point. So you have to assign variables and jump to a single `return` statement

> Rule 6–6–5 (Required) A function shall have a single point of exit at
> the end of the function.

Error handling is the only place where using `goto` is actually encouraged. Linux Kernel Coding style presents and encourages using `goto` to "keep all exit points close". The style is not enforced - not all kernel functions use this. See [Linux kernel coding style # Centralized exiting of functions](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html#centralized-exiting-of-functions).

The kernel recommendation of `goto` was adopted by SEI-C: [MEM12-C. Consider using a goto chain when leaving a function on error when using and releasing resources](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/MEM12-C.+Consider+using+a+goto+chain+when+leaving+a+function+on+error+when+using+and+releasing+resources).

> Does the do { } while(0); pattern qualify?

Sure, why not. If you do not allocate any more resources inside the `do { .. here .. }while(0)` block, you might as well write a separate function and then call `return` from it.

There are also expansions on the idea. Even implementations of exceptions in C using `longjmp`. I know of [ThrowTheSwitch/CException](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/CException).

Overall, error handling in C is not easy. Handling errors from multiple libraries becomes extremely hard and is an art of its own. See [MBed OS error-handling](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v6.15/apis/error-handling.html), [mbed_error.h](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/a3be10c976c36da222517abc0cb4f81e88ff8552/platform/include/platform/mbed_error.h#L71), even [a site that explains MBed OS error codes](https://armmbed.github.io/mbedos-error/).

Strongly prefer single return point from your functions - as you found out, using your `CHECK(errorcode);` will leak resources. Multiple `return` places are confusing. Consider using `goto`s:

```
int somefunction() {
    int errorcode = 0;

    handle_t res1 = getResource();
    if (!res1) {
        errorcode = somethnig;
        goto res1_fail;
    }
    handle_t res2 = getResource();
    if (!res2) {
        errorcode = somethnig_else;
        goto res2_fail;
    }

    errorcode = action1(res1, res2);
    if (!errorcode) {
       goto actions_fail;
    }
    errorcode = action2(res1, res2);
    if (!errorcode) {
       goto actions_fail;
    }

actions_fail:
    freeResource(res2);
res2_fail:
    freeResource(res1);
res1_fail:
    return errorcode;
}
```

Comment: Regarding MISRA-C and multiple returns, see the link in my answer. Also note that MISRA-C:2004 and MISRA-C++:2008 both ban `goto`. MISRA-C:2012 was however relaxed to allow the use of `goto` as demonstrated in your code example.

Comment: there as an annoyance with this solution. Resource/acquire and release are quite spatially separated. This is cumbersome for the long chains. Moreover, the ordering is important what is very easy to break when refactoring something in the middle of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mysterious macros such as your `CHECKERROR` which hide away flow control are widely considered very bad practice. Don't do that - creating secret macro languages that no other C programmer understands is a much more serious quality concern than code repetition. Code repetition isn't good but it shouldn't be solved by creating a much worse problem. Assume that the reader knows C well, but don't assume that they know or want to know your secret macro language local to this project.

In idiomatic C there are two acceptable ways to write this code. Either with explicit `return` or with the "on error goto" pattern à la BASIC. I would generally recommend the `return` version since it saves you from having that old tiresome "`goto` considered harmful" debate yet again. But goto to a clean-up at the end of the function is acceptable too, as long as you only jump downwards.

(Your `do-while(0)` with `break` is just a `goto` in disguise. It isn't better or worse.)

The single point of `return` from functions is also debated, especially in the context of MISRA-C (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42577015/584518)). Multiple returns from a function is however *fine* as long as it doesn't make the code harder to read. In practice this means that you should avoid `return` (or `goto`) from inside deeply nested loops or statements. Generally keep the "cyclomatic complexity" (the number of possible execution paths in a function) as low as possible.

In case you need to free up resources, I personally prefer `return` over `goto`. For `return` you need to make a wrapper function, which also serves the purpose of separating resource allocation from the algorithm. I would have rewritten your code like this:

```
typedef enum // use an actual enum not sloppy int
{
  OK, // keeping code 0 for no error is the most common practice
  ERR_THIS,
  ERR_THAT
} err_t;

static err_t the_actual_algorithm (handle_t res1, handle_t res2) // likely inlined
{
   err_t errorcode;

   errorcode = action1(res1, res2);
   if(errorcode != OK) { return errorcode; }

   errorcode = action2(res1, res2);
   if(errorcode != OK) { return errorcode; }

   return OK;
}

err_t somefunction (void)  // note void, not empty parenthesis which is obsolete style
{
    handle_t res1, res2;
    err_t errorcode;

    res1 = getResource();
    res2 = getResource();

    errorcode = the_actual_algorithm(res1, res2);
 
    freeResource(res1);
    freeResource(res2);
    return errorcode;
}
```